# Custom property Binding error: property doesn't exist in component

Tags: angular, typescript

Error while transferring data from parent component to child component.

I have a product-list component

product-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent {
products=[{
id:1,
name:'Nike',
description:'test test lorem ipsum text',
brand:'Nike',
gender:'MEN',
category:'RUNNING',
size:[6,7,8,9],
color:['Wgite','Blue','Black'],
price:160,
discountedprice:120,
is_in_inventory:true,
items_left:3,
imageURL:'assets/image/iphone.png',
slug:'nike-air-max'
}
```

product-list.component.html

```
<app-product *ngFor="Let pod of products" [product]="pod"></app-product>
```

Child component of the above component

product.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.css']
})
export class ProductComponent {
@Input()
product: {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  brand: string;
  gender: string;
  category: string;
  size: number[];
  color: string[];
  price: number;
  discountedprice?: number;
  is_in_inventory: boolean;
  items_left: number;
  imageURL: string;
  slug: string;
};

}
```

product.component.html

```
<tr >
<td>
    <img [src]="product.imageURL" width="50px" height="100px">
    <div>
        {{product.price}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="product.discountedprice">
        {{(100-(product.discountedprice/product.price*100)).toFixed(0)}}% OFF
    </div>
    <div>
        {{product.name}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{product.gender}} {{product.category}} {{product.brand}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{product.color.length}} Colors. Best Seller
    </div>
    <div [ngStyle]="{fontweight: 'bold',color: product.is_in_inventory ? 'Green':'Red'}">
        {{product.is_in_inventory ? 'Available':'Not Available'}} 
    </div>
</td>
</tr>
```

I am getting the below error while running ng serve command
**Property 'pod' does not exist on type 'ProductListComponent'.**

I have made a child component trying to get value using @Input

Don't know I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just made a typo, it's `let`, not `Let` in your `*ngFor`.